# How to pass the type of a variable to a template method?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I think the best explanation is an example. I have 2 different variables of different types, and I want their type max values:

```
int iVal;
size_t sVal;

auto iMax = std::numeric_limits<**??**(iVal)>::max();
auto sMax = std::numeric_limits<**??**(sVal)>::max();
```

So, is there a method to replace ?? with something that will give me the max size? I did not manage to make neiter typeof nor typeid do the trick.
One change which would solve the problem would be if ::max() method would receive a parameter, this could be achieved by template deduction:

```
auto iMax = std::numeric_limits::max(iVal);
```

Why I need this: I am using a 3rd party code which might change some of the types and I would like be safe against this. I know about `static_assert()`, which I am using now, but still, I was wondering if there is a method of achieving variable-to-type for templates.

Comment: Use `decltype(iVal)`. Note that `typeof` is not in the standard C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decltype` is used to deduce type of an expression. Here you can use it like:

```
auto iMax = std::numeric_limits<decltype(iVal)>::max();
auto sMax = std::numeric_limits<decltype(sVal)>::max();
```

or additionally you can form a template function to do it for you:

```
template<typename T>
auto maxof(const T&){
    return std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
}
```

and then use it by:

```
auto iMax = maxof(iVal);
auto sMax = maxof(sVal);
```

Comment: having  `maxof` to return auto as well would be a good idea IMHO

Comment: @OznOg you are right, thank you . I will make the changes.

Comment: you could also pass a const  reference to your function so thatvalue does not get copied